# Drupal node reference

Tags: drupal, drupal-nodes

I am using two content types - test_parent & test_child
In test_child there are two fields, both of type datetime
And in test_parent there are two fields, week_no & 7 node references

I am using node_save to save a new node.
After saving a node of parent type, and then saving the node of child type, i want to update the node it into the parent type.

I have completed creation of both nodes from code, and also i am able to update nid in parent type from code.

The problem is, the change in db is getting reflected in db but not on drupal node view.
Even if i edit the node from drupal, it's showing -none- selected in node reference.

Please help.

Comment: More details needed. Is the change not reflected within the same page cycle only or also after a reload? Could you edit your question to show the code you use to update the parent?

Comment: yes on page reload even.

Comment: By the way, thanx Henrik, got it solved.
After updating a node from code, i cleared the cache related to that node.
I checked the node edit code in core module, and got the answer from them.
Thanx anyways.

Comment: You should post that as answer and then accept it. That way people looking at the same problem will find the actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

Two modules that can help with this kind of thing...

http://drupal.org/project/cnr

http://drupal.org/project/noderelationships

I was going to suggest to be careful you're creating the nodes and applying the relationships through the proper Drupal API channels, but it sound like it was a node caching issue.

Comment: Thanx josh, sounds really good.